# How to add onMouseEnter on an react element located inside a link tag

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, mouseevent

I wonder how to add event `onMouseEnter` on an react element that is located inside a link tag:

```
<a href="url">
  <Container>
    <div onMouseEnter={() => console.log('onMouseEnter on div')}>
      ...
    </div>
  </Container>
</a>
```

doesn't work for me

I cannot change the structure of the code (put `Container` outside of the link) because I work on a extension that add some data on Instagram feed website, thus the `a` tag is from instagram.

Comment: It seems to work natively : https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-wave-esng2

Comment: Maybe something's wrong with the container

Comment: @HichamELBSI yes you right it seems to work natively, maybe there are some conflict with instagram pages